# How can I modify the program so that the delay for every interval the led turns On and Off increases by 1 seconds Everytime the loop restarts

Tags: arduino-uno

It's my first time learning arduino uno and I do not know what to do

```
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

int ledState = LOW;  

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

const long interval = 1000;

void setup() {
  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    for(int interval = 500; interval >= 20; interval++)
    
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

The delay for every interval the led turns On and Off increases by 1 seconds everytime the loop restarts.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you ask your question in the question itself, not the title and also give us some more information about what you're trying to accomplish, what's working and what isn't working so we can help.

If I understand correctly, you want the LED to stay on longer and longer each time it blinks. First cycle 1 second, second cycle 2 seconds, third cycle 3 seconds, etc. You are pretty close, just need some tweaking of your logic.

```
void loop() {
  
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) { //Check if LED duration has expired
    //Toggle LED
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }
    interval += 1000; //Increase the interval by 1 second
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState); //Set the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis; //Set the time of the last transition to now
  }
}
```

Comment: `interval` is `const`.

Comment: please don't chat in answer. with a little more rep you will be able to comment. until then answer questions which don't require clarification from the OP.